# reduce vertices and triangles for plane made with unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a plane using unity. The thing is that this plane has 200 triangles and 100+ vertices. Because my plane is not altered( i only set a texture on it), i think that the plane should have 2 triangles and 4 vertices. Can this be done?

UPDATE:
i think i need to change the mesh filter for my plane. I've created one with only 4 vertices in blender, but after i delete the original plane mesh in unity and place the new 4-vertices mesh, i only get a color that can be found on my texture, but not the texture itself. Can i place a texture on a 4 vertices mesh? if so, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Using a 4 vertices/2 triangles planes should work, and is also a good idea :-)

It's probably only showing part of the texture because it has some wrong UV coordinates.

Try using this plane:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4375689/Permanent/Plane.3DS

I'm not sure if the size is correct, but it should have the correct UV coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

That is right, the default Unity plane has more than 2 tris and 4 vertices. To have such a mesh you need to either import it or create it in code.

I've built this script called ProceduralPlane that allows you to set the number of segments in the editor: https://github.com/doukasd/Unity-Components/tree/master/UnityPackages